# MessageEnumerator.MoveNext() error from remote server - C#

Tags: msmq

I have created one console app where i implemented search message from MSMQ functionality for specific criteria (Label/ Body / Priority).

```
MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=OS:(MachineName A)\private$\TestQueue")
msgQ.Label = "Label test"  // Simlarly i set search criteria

MessageEnumerator msgEnumtr = msgQ.GetMessageEnumerator2(); // Search Queue

While(msgEnumtr.MoveNext(timeout)) // This line works fine in MSMQ server, not working remote server.
{
  Message currentMsg= msgEnumtr.Current;
}
```

Here "TestQueue" is the private queue set up in "Machine A". I have given Anonymous Login rights for this queue.

I am running my console application from "Machine B" connected in the same LAN. MSMQ components also enabled/installed on this machine. When i run my console exe here, getting "Object reference not set to an instance" error at "While(msgEnumtr.MoveNext(timeout))" line. Sometime i am getting following error "cursor is not currently pointing to Message instance".

But when i run this exe from "Machine A", its working fine & searching as expected.

(Note : queue.Send(Msg) - (Put message to queue) Works fine in both machine, only issue with search functionality)

Anybody can help me out on this. Thanks.

Comment: Try to call queue.Receive on machine B. There is different rights to send and to read in msmq.

Comment: Yes. But i need to get all the messages from queue which matching my criteria. "Receive" will return only first message (one).

Comment: even queue.Receive , i am getting the same error in "Machine B"